# How to contrast “but...while”?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, meaning-in-context

Consider, in attempting to translate:

> *Ah, you like sushi? Have you tried poke? Both have fish (usually raw) and rice. **But** sushi is Japanese, **while** poke is Hawaiian.*

↓

> Ha, vi ŝatas suŝion, ĉu? Ĉu pokeon vi iam provis? <del>La ambaŭ</del> *Ambaŭ*  enhavas (kutime krudan) fiŝaĵon kun rizo. **Sed?** suŝio estas japana, **dum?** pokeo estas havaja.

It isn’t clear to me the best way to draw a distinction like this. Is this a case for *kvankam*? A rewording with *kiel … tiel*? *Ankoraŭ*? Leave out the fine meaning and just go with *sed, … kaj*? Something else?

Is my problem here trying to contrast the copulas (*estas*) where I should be contrasting the predicates, so something more like *(Sed) suŝio estas japana, **??** pokeo, **??** havaja*?

I note in English

- But while sushi is Japanese, poke is Hawaiian
- Yet sushi is Japanese while poke*[*, | is*]* Hawaiian
- But although sushi is Japanese, poke is Hawaiian
- But sushi is Japanese; poke, Hawaiian
- Sushi, however, is Japanese, and poke is Hawaiian

all seem nearly identical in connotation. But the Esperanto alternatives seem to draw sharper distinctions, which is why I’m having trouble—I feel like I almost need the equivalent of *je* for contrasts and comparisons.

Comment: I know my usage of _la ambaŭ_ vs. _la du manĝaĵoj_ or something else is a subject of discussion, too—I just went with a Zamenhof construction I found in La Tekstaro.

Comment: La vorto _ambaŭ_ jam referencas du specifajn aferojn, do prefere _la_ ne staru antaŭ _ambaŭ_. El [PIV](http://vortaro.net/#amba%C5%AD): “Z[amenhof] iufoje uzis «la ambaŭ», sed poste konfesis, ke «pli logike estas uzi la vorton ambaŭ sen art[ikolo].” Plue, la rimarko en PIV ĉe [kvankam](http://vortaro.net/#kvankam) povas esti utila por vi.

Comment: @Joffysloffy Yikes, what bad luck!—Usually, if I find a Zamenhof construction in La Tekstaro that initially “felt right”, I feel like I’m really starting to become fluent. I’m honestly not at a high enough level yet with abstract vocabulary for the PIV to be useful to me often for functional words, or I would’ve seen this. I’m surprised I missed the PMEG, though—I read it but must have misread the _la_ part.

Comment: Don't forget **aliflanke**, it may be useful too.

Comment: Suŝio kaj pokeo ambaŭ estas fiŝ**aĵo**j, kiun enhavas fiŝ**o**n.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Ambaŭ enhavas (kutime krudan) fiŝaĵon kun rizo. Sed suŝio estas
>   japana, **dum** pokeo estas havaja.

**dum** = kontraste kun tio, ke... (vidu [PIV, *dum* II- 2](http://vortaro.net/#dum))

Ekz. el Tekstaro:

> Latin-Ameriko kaj Azio sekvas tiun lastan tendencon, sed Nord-Ameriko
>   kreskas malpli forte (0,4%), dum Eŭropo estas kvazaŭ senkreska.

---

PMEG ([15.5. Ambaŭ](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/oa-vortecaj_vortetoj/ambau.html)):

> *Ambaŭ* estas difinilo. Tial oni ne povas uzi *la* kune kun *ambaŭ*.

Answer (score 1):

I think I would say "kaj" in this situation if you aren't aiming to emphasise the distinction but rather suggest that they related but slightly different:

> Ha, vi ŝatas suŝion, ĉu? Ĉu pokeon vi iam provis? Ambaŭ enhavas fiŝaĵon kun rizo. Sed suŝio estas japana, *kaj* pokeo estas havaja.

If you did want to emphasise the difference, then something like:

> ... Sed suŝio estas japana, malkiel pokeo, kiu estas havaja.

or

> ... Tamen suŝio estas japana, sed pokeo estas havaja.